# Mouse delay only when moving around in Minecraft Java Edition?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues, pc, mouse

Since about a month ago I've had really bad mouse delay in Minecraft. I haven't changed any settings, installed any programs, or anything else that could cause this sort of issue.

The problem only exists ingame *while moving around* - when I go into my inventory and move my cursor, there seems to be no mouse delay at all.

I've tried multiple ways of debugging this to no avail.

- The issue seems to only occur in Minecraft, in all other games the mouse is fine
- I have tested different mice (one wired, one wireless) with no difference
- The problem persists if I use Badlion or the normal Minecraft launcher

I've updated my computer, changed settings according to other peoples mouse delay problems, changed servers, changed versions, but nothing seems to fix it.

Here's 2 video links to showcase the problem. Both videos are at 8x slowmo. Pay attention to the cursor on the pause menu, vs the camera in-game:

- https://streamable.com/w8bt0s
- https://streamable.com/afgs1f

What could cause this issue? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

You may have somehow turned on the **Cinematic camera**.

Check in your *Controls* settings which key toggles *Cinematic camera*. If it is not currently assigned, you can assign an unused key. Then, return to thje game and press the key.

Comment: What FPS do you get (on the F3 screen)? It is a bit hard to tell - I counted 10 frames in about 4 seconds, which (at x8 slowmo) would give 20 FPS which is too low and might be causing the apparent delay.